# How would a 'commentable' polymorphic association work on a 'user' model itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm learning rails and trying out polymorphic association. I have listed below a couple of simple models for illustration. Model associations seems to works fine as expected. But what if a user (commenter) would like to leave a comment for a another user? I can't seems to get it to work with these configuration. How do I go about doing so?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  #  username, email, password_digest
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  # title, completed, user_id
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  # commenter_id, commentable_type, commentable_id, body
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

in console... setup

```
user1 = User.frist
user2 = User.last
project = Project.first

pro_comment = project.comments.new(body: 'some text')
pro_comment.commenter_id = user1.id
pro_comment.save

user_comment = user2.comments.new(body: 'some text')
user_comment.commenter_id = user1.id
user_comment.save
```

expected and actual results

```
Comment.all => successfully lists pro_comment & user_comment

But...
Comment.find_by(commenter_id: 1) => only listed the pro_comment 
(what am I doing wrong?)
```

*Also..
user1.comments => returned an empty object... was expecting 2 objects, 
as you can see below it's not referencing 'commenter_id' ....
result...*

```
comment Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE 
"comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2 
LIMIT $3  [["commentable_id", 1], ["commentable_type", "User"], 
["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

*I also tried ...
user1.comments.where(commenter_id: 1) >> which returned...*

```
comment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE
 "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2 
AND "comments"."commenter_id" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["commentable_id", 1],
["commentable_type", "User"], ["commenter_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could someone please point me in the right direction. 
I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_by` returns only one record, try `Comment.where(commenter_id: 1)` instead.

For `user1.comments` being empty, you are mixing the relationships. You should have 2 relationships: comment belongs to a commentable object (a project or a user) and comments also belongs to a commenter (the user you set as commenter_id).

It makes sense for `user1.comments` to be empty since the user is the commenter on both comments, it's not the commentable. `user2.comments` shouldn't be empty, same for `project.comments`

Try something like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments_done, class_name: 'Comment', inverse_of: :commenter
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commenter, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

(check the guide, I may be missing some config option https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)

Now you can use `user1.comments_done` and `user1.comments` for comments done by the user and done at the user.

Comment: Thank you so much!!. Oh boy! that was an stuff one to grasp. I certainly had things confused. Your solution worked, _except I had to replace inverse_of: :commenter with foreign_key: :commenter_id_